# Bash background color changing for accented character

Tags: python, bash, colors, background

Basically, I'm using python to print out some information in the terminal and some of the text included accented characters, such as Thai language. When I use try this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding: UTF-8
#test.py

import sys

print "\033[41mลองดู\033[0m" #there is an accented character at the end.
```

Therefore the whole sentence is not background coloured. The terminal omits the last character of the sentence. Is there anyway to fix that? Thanks so much.

Comment: There is nothing Bash-related in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accent is considered outside of the cell for the purposes of text attributes. Output some spaces before resetting the attributes if you want the accent to appear with the background.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, but is there anyway to automate that. In case that I don't know what the output might be or how many accent characters I might get.

Comment: Not really. If you need more accurate rendering then write a GUI app instead.